# CSS absolute position and not relative to its absolute parent div

Tags: html, css

There is a parent div which has absolute positioning with a child having absolute positioning. 
My problem is to make the child div relative to the whole page not to its parent:

Example:

```css
.parent { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: move 2s infinite;
}
.child { 
  position: fixed;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: purple;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes move {
50% {
transform: translateX(25px);
}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**The goal is** to make the little purple div fixed in top left of screen and hidden when the big blue div blue move outside it. I tried `sticky - fixed` with same result.

Comment: Then the elements should be siblings. You'll need to position the "child" elsewhere in the DOM to make that work

Comment: By this, i cant make use of `overflow: hidden` and the div wont be hidden

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152712/css-positionfixed-inside-of-positionabsolute

Comment: looks related to the use of Transform

Comment: @GarrGodfrey https://stackoverflow.com/q/15194313/8620333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use animation in opposite direction for the child element and this will make child element look like its static in one position.

```css
.parent {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: move 2s infinite;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: purple;
  animation: moveBack 2s infinite;
  z-index: 2;
}

@keyframes move {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(25px);
  }
}

@keyframes moveBack {
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-25px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yup this should marked as solved, but unfortunately this did not worked in my project because of multiple transition effects applied to my div, I'll try to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Absolute positioning behaves like relative positioning for child divs.

You have to move the child div outside the parent div to make it fixed relative to the page/ body.

Otherwise `child` will always positioned relative to `parent`

Comment: By this, i cant make use of `overflow: hidden` and the div wont be hidden

Comment: What is your intention with `overflow: hidden`?

Comment: To hide the purple child when the blue div move outside it

Answer (score 0):

You can consider an idea using `clip-path` animation

```css
.parent { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 125px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: move 2s infinite;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0, calc(100% - 25px) 0,calc(100% - 25px) 100%, 0 100%);
}
.child { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: purple;
}

@keyframes move {
50% {
  clip-path:polygon(25px 0, 100% 0,100% 100%, 25px 100%);
}
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also working answer, but I made the example simple by making my div as rectangle, but its way more complex and can't be drawn in clip-path.

Comment: @KareemDabbeet share then your *real and complex* example. Actually we can only help based on the code you gave. No one can give you an accurate solution that will work for you since no one know the real use case

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .parent { 
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 10px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            background-color: blue;
            overflow: hidden;
            animation: move 2s infinite;
        }
        .child { 
            position: fixed;
            top: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            background-color: purple;
            z-index: 2;
        }
        @keyframes move {
            50% {
                transform: translateX(25px);
            }
        }
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The position of your child has to be absolute. Absolute positioning has to do with the page itself.

Comment: The child is already absolutely positioned. The issue is that the parent is also absolutely positioned, which causes the child's absolute position to be anchored to the parent instead of the page.

Comment: Yes, that is true. But you have to understand that I was talking about the first script on the page.